# Formulário na view com sub-formulários em partialView

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Caros amigos, tenho uma `view` que contém apenas `@model Projeto.Models.Oc` e um *form*. Dentro deste *form*, tenho botões que chamam *MODAL*, esses *MODAL* possuem `partialView` que possui outro *form* e `@model Projeto.Models.Rc`, `@model Projeto.Models.Pc`, etc.

Eu queria saber qual a tratativa para esta necessidade, pois acredito que essas *strong type* na `view` principal e nas `partialViews` estão conflitando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `<form>` deve sempre ficar apenas na View pai. As Views parciais atém podem ter campos do `<form>`, mas dentro delas você não pode usar `<form>`, até porque o HTML nem coloca um `<form>` dentro de outro.

Quanto a especificar os `strong types` para cada *partial*, não há problemas, desde que para cada *partial* seja passado o tipo correto. Ou seja, suponho que para a *View* pai, que tem a seguinte declaração:

```
@model Projeto.Models.Oc
```

As *partials* sejam chamadas assim:

```
@Html.Partial("_MinhaPartial", Model.Rc)
```

Ou então assim:

```
@Html.Partial("_MinhaPartial", new Projeto.Models.Rc())
```

Comment: Cigano, estou usando na view Create conforme disse acima, porém, na view Edit, preciso passar o o parametro ticket para que a partialView venha preenchida. Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Neste caso, você cria um *ViewModel*, que é uma classe com a classe que antes era declarada como `@model` dentro, mais uma *property* chamada `Ticket`. No `POST`, seu Controller recebe como parâmetro esse *ViewModel*.

Answer (score 1):

Crie propriedades na sua model principal do tipo das models que serão carregadas em suas partials. Assim você só precisa referenciar uma única model em sua view, independentemente do que suas partials views podem carregar. Por exemplo:

```
public class ModelPrincipal
{
   //Depois de você declarar as propriedades dessa model, 
   //declare a propriedade da model que trabalhara na partial View
   public ModelSecundaria modelSecundaria {get; set;}

}
```

Depois disso alimente em sua Action a sua model, de acordo com o seu negócio e referencie em sua PartialView como se fosse uma propriedade normal:

```
 @Html.Partial("_MyPartial", Model.modelSecundaria);
```