# Retorno após HttpPost em Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Boa noite,

Estou trabalhando com tabs do Bootstrap 3, e tenho a seguinte estrutura:

View.cshtml

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab_cooperado" class="tab-pane fade">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView", new Model());}
    </div>
    <div id="tab_visitantes" class="tab-pane fade">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView_2", new Model_2());}
    </div>       
</div>
```

Sendo que tenho um botão dentro de um Form na partial

PArtialView.cshtml

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" id='pesquisar' class="btn.large btn-danger btn-block" value="Limpar" name="p_comando">
 </div>
```

Controler:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Metodo(Model p_Model)
    {
        //... alteraçoes no model
        return PartialView("~/PartialView.cshtml", p_model);
    }
```

Ao clicar no botão, consigo capturar o evento e fazer minhas alterações no model da partialView, mas ao retornar, somente a partial view aparece, ao invés de vir atualizada dentro da View. Alguem pode me dizer como proceder? Obrigado!

**EDIT 2:**

Models:

```
    namespace Web.Models
    {
        public class MainModel
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public PartialModel_1 partialModel_1 { get; set; }
            public PartialModel_2 partialModel_2 { get; set; }
        }

        public class PartialModel_1
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string nome { get; set; }
        }

        public class PartialModel_2
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string nome { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

View Principal:

```
    @model Web.Models.MainModel

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs form-tabs">
        <li id="basic-list" class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_cooperado">Aba_1</a>

        </li>
        <li class="" id="team_details-list">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_visitantes">Aba_2</a>

        </li>
    </ul>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("MainMetodo", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab_cooperado" class="tab-pane fade active in">
                @Html.Partial("Partial1", Model.partialModel_1 ?? new Web.Models.PartialModel_1())
            </div>
            <div id="tab_visitantes" class="tab-pane fade">
                @Html.Partial("Partial2", Model.partialModel_2 ?? new Web.Models.PartialModel_2())
            </div>
        </div>

    }
```

Partial_1:

```
    @model Web.Models.PartialModel_1

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id)
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.id)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nome)
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nome)
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <input type="submit" class="btn.large btn-success btn-block" value="Pesquisar" name="p_comando" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Partial_2:

```
    @model Web.Models.PartialModel_2

    <div class="row">
        <div class="span1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.id)
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.id)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span1">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nome)
        </div>
        <div class="span2">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nome)
        </div><div class="span4">
        <input type="submit" class="btn.large btn-success btn-block" value="Pesquisar" name="p_comando" />
    </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
    namespace Web.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult About()
            {
                MainModel model = new MainModel();
                return View(model);
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult MainMetodo(MainModel model)
            {
                //Partials chegam nulas no Model!!

                //Oque devo retornar aqui, para que somente o valor da PARTIAL view
                //onde o botão foi clicado, seja atualizado dentro da minha aba!!
                return View(model);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Se ta querendo atualizar isso com Ajax (JQuery)?

Answer (score 1):

O erro parece bastante simples: você não está retornando a *View* toda porque está usando uma construção indevida, no caso, esta:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView", new Model());}
@{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView_2", new Model_2());}
```

O correto seria usar assim:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView", Model.Cooperado ?? new Model());}
@{Html.RenderPartial("PartialView_2", Model.Visitantes ?? new Model_2());}
```

O operador `??` garante que se a parte à esquerda for nula, você possa passar uma alternativa do lado direito. Portanto, garante a geração das *Partials* livres de erros, instanciando objetos novos se os passados estão nulos.

E no Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Metodo(Model p_Model)
{
    //... alteraçoes no model
    return View(p_model);
}
```

Para gerar a *Partial* corretamente, é preciso gerar a *View* corretamente. Por isso o retorno é `View()`.

---

EDIT

Tem mais algumas coisas faltando. Na *View* principal, faltou um `@using (Html.BeginForm())` e a chave primária escondida:

```
@model Web.ViewModels.Fenicoopa.Recepcao

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RecepcaoId)

    <div class="col-md-7">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs form-tabs" id="tab_recepcao">
            <li class="">
                <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_cooperado">Cooperados</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab_cooperado" class="tab-pane fade">
            @Html.RenderPartial("BuscaCooperado", Model.m_CooperadoComDependente ?? new Web.ViewModels.Fenicoopa.CooperadoComDependentes())
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Você esta dizendo que o Post chamado pelo botão na partial view tem que ser capturado no controller da View?

Comment: Ele vai ser capturado de qualquer forma, pois é assim que o ASP.NET MVC funciona.

Comment: Entendi. Fiz as alterações recomendadas, mas estou com problema no Metodo do Controler. Os membros p_Model (model principal) sempre vem nulos após o clique no botão. Tenho o MainModel que possui 2 Membros que também são objetos. Ao clicar no botao na partial view apos ter preenchido o formulario, o model membro chega nulo no controlador.

Comment: Você pode colocar na pergunta o código inteiro da View principal?

Comment: Editei. Dei uma enchugada nos códigos, mas acho que coloquei o importante. Andei pesquisando e parece q eu tenho que usar o Html Helper para "escrever" os campos da partial ja na main view mesmo eles ja estando atribuidos na partial? Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Alguma ideia do que devo fazer?

Comment: @Doug_js Editei novamente a resposta.

Comment: Ola cigano. Obrigado pelas respostas. Estou com um ultimo problema para ter o resultado esperado. O meu caso é identico ao deste [link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12060/formul%C3%A1rio-na-view-com-sub-formul%C3%A1rios-em-partialview/12068#12068) em que você ajudou. O meu problema, é como eu devo realizar o return no metodo POST. Eu tentei com "Return PartialView(modelPartialViewModificado)", mas desta forma eu perco a View junto com o "Layout". Oque eu espero, que o model da partial view seja alterado e retorne as alterações na partial view que esta dentro da aba.

Comment: @Doug_js Você pode por favor colocar esse método que recebe o `POST` na sua pergunta?

Comment: Cigano, montei um esquema resumido igual ao que tenho na minha aplicação e coloquei no post dentro do EDIT 2. As duvidas que tenho, estão no comentario do metodo do controlador. Basicamente, eu tenho uma view principal com 2 partials views que possuem um botão cada. Ao dar submit no botão da partial, eu gostaria que somente o conteudo da mesma seja atualizado.

Comment: Experimente trocar `public ActionResult MainMetodo(MainModel model)` por `public ActionResult MainMetodo(FormCollection collection)`. O que vem em `collection`?

Comment: Trás as "Keys" do Form "id", "nome", "p_comando" (sendo esse ultimo do botao) no objeto final. Ao navegar pela hierarquia de obejtos, localizo os valores postados no formalurio em arrays.

Comment: E tem tudo o que você precisa ou falta coisas?